# prove that $x \mapsto \mathrm e^{-x}$ has a unique fixed point on R

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

Can anybody prove $x \mapsto \mathrm e^{-x}$ has a unique fixed point on R using the fixed point iteration theorem?

Comment: A good start would be to state the point iteration theorem. And yes, we can try to prove the result. Did you do it?

Comment: $x \mapsto e^{-x}$ is **not** a contraction on $\Bbb{R}$, so you will have trouble applying the fixed point theorem directly.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Could it be that the OP forgot to state that $x\geq 0$ or something like that?

Comment: @String: As Martin-Blas Perez Pinilla points out, you only have to consider $x\mapsto e^{-x}$ on the image of itself, which is $(0,\infty)$ and on this set, $e^{-x}$ is contractive.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Right! I saw that short after I posted my comment. I voted for him too ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image of the function is $(0,+\infty)$ and in this set $x\mapsto e^{-x}$ is contractive.

Answer (score 1):

Define the function $f : x \to \mathrm e ^{-x} -x$ and remark that its derivative is strictly negative. 
Then $f$ is strictly decreasing, plus we have $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=\mathrm e^{-1} -1 <0$.

It is sufficient to conclude by using the intermediate value theorem and the monotonicity that $f$ has a unique zero in $\mathbb R$ (and more precisely in $\left[0,1 \right]$)